# Do the Amazon web service APIs support barcode/UPC queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, barcode

I skimmed through their documentation and found it a bit overwhelming at first. I know you can search for items by entering a UPC (the number below a 1D barcode), but I couldn't find a word about it in the API.

What I want to do is perform a product lookup by doing a UPC search after scanning a barcode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a page from the [https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/use-cases/search-with-external-identifiers.html](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) which shows how you can use the ItemLookup method to find a specific product by UPC.

Note that default IdType for the ItemLookup is ASIN, but you can change it to something else like UPC if you need to

Comment: perfect, thanks!

On a side note... it's interesting to see how even Amazon still don't understand what RESTful service APIs are. I stumbled upon this:



Using ItemLookup (REST)

The following ItemLookup example demonstrates a request for item information for an ASIN.

http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService
    &SubscriptionId=[ID]
    &Operation=ItemLookup
    &ItemId=[An ASIN]
   
that URL violates every principle behind a RESTful interface design... but well, as long as it does the job, who am I to complain :)

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken  :(  Any chance you can find the page again and correct the link?  Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's now called the "Product Advertising API", but I updated the link above to this:  http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html

Comment: url changed to https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/use-cases/search-with-external-identifiers.html

Answer (score 11):

Be carefull if you want to use the Amazon web services API on a mobile device !

We've found this in the Amazon.com Product Advertising API License Agreement:

> 4) Usage Requirements
>
> (e) **You will not,** without our express prior written approval, use
>   any Product Advertising Content on or in connection with any site or
>   application designed or intended **for use with a mobile phone or
>   other handheld device,** or any television set-top box ....

[Link to Amazon.com Product Advertising API License Agreement](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_t=501&ref_=amb_link_83957651_1&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-1&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_i=assoc-api-detail-5-v2)

Any Ideas for an alternative ItemLookup method to find a specific product by UPC/Barcode ?

Comment: Whoops, perhaps I should get used to reading T&Cs without just checking the box below... Thanks!

Comment: Yep, this is what got the Delicious Library iPhone app killed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, the Amazon web service APIs does support barcode/UPC queries. Any information / documentation are to be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_LookupbyUPC.html).

If you want to generate barcodes, maybe [this](http://upc-lookup.com/upc-generator/) helps?

Cheers, Tim

Answer (score 0):

With IdType request parameters ( [see documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) ) not only for upc, but also support ean and isbn query